# Is the fractional integral of order 1/2 of an L_2 function continuous

Tags: fourier-analysis, fractional-calculus

Let $R_\alpha f(t) = \int_0^t (t-s)^{-\alpha} f(s)\,ds$ the fractional integration operator. If $f \in L_q(0,1)$ for some $q>2$ then $R_{1/2} f$ is (even Hölder) continuous on $[0,1]$.

My question is what happens in the endpoint: does $R_{1/2}$ map $L_2(0,1)$  to $C([0,1])$?

thank you very much, Bernhard

Comment: maybe try looking up a Young's convolution inequality with the weak $L^p$ spaces...  I think it may follow from some of that stuff.

Comment: A look in Grafakos Thm 1.2.13 gives $f \ast g \in L_q$ for $1/q + 1 = 1/p + 1/r$ when $f \in L_p$ and $g \in L_{r, \infty}$. However, the endpoint $q=\infty$ is wrong (on $\mathbb R$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no as the following example shows: Let 
 $$
  F(t)= \begin{cases} a_nt^{-\frac 12+b_n},& t\in [t_{n+1},t_n),\quad n\geq 1,\\
                      0,& \text{otherwise,}
      \end{cases}
  $$
where $0< t_{n+1}< t_n<1$, $n\geq 1$. Then $F\in L^2(0,1)$ provided
  $$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n^2}{2b_n}(t_n^{2b_n}-t_{n+1}^{2b_n}) < \infty
   $$
 and $\int_0^1 t^{-\frac 12} F(t)\, dt = +\infty$ provided
   $$
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}(t_n^{b_n}-t_{n+1}^{b_n})= \infty.
   $$
 Now we  choose $a_n= \frac 1{n^2} e^n$,  $b_n=\frac 1n$, $t_n=e^{-n^2}$, and take $f(t)= F(1-t)$, $t\in [0,1]$ and we conclude that $f\in L^2(0,1)$ but $R_{1/2}f\notin C([0,1])$.